# Bootstrap3 : navbar-form float right and margin of input forms in mobile browser

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 problems about navbar using bootstrap3

1. following code, `<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form">`,
   set class to navbar-right. But these forms didn't move right.
   (Also, these forms can not move whether the class name is navbar-left or navbar-right.)
2. in mobile browser, 2 forms can not be showed totally especially its width(both side) is cut.

how can i solve them?

Thank you in advance.

http://www.bootply.com/tanJWih5tr

```
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
             </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form">
                <!-- i already set class "navbar-right", but these forms don't align to right -->        
                  <div class="form-group">        
                    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>        
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Enter email">        
                  </div>        
                  <div class="form-group">        
                      <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2">Password</label>        
                      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="Password">        
                  </div>        
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Sign in</button>        
                </form>        
              </ul>        
            </div>        
          </div>
        </nav>
```

Comment: Form's parent (ul) is having a smaller width and hence form doesn't  look on the right. If you add the class `col-md-11` to `ul` then the form will go to the right. Also a `ul` should always have `li` as it's child element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have closed the tag `<ul>` in the wrong place.

Make it this way

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form"> <!-- i already set class "navbar-right", but these forms don't align to right -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Enter email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Sign in</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```